# Unable to run windows command using subprocess.Popen

Tags: windows, subprocess, python-3.9

I'm trying to run a simple windows command `dir E:\Projects\ML /s /b` using `subprocess.Popen` function without using `Shell=True`, my sample program is below

```
import subprocess
import os
import time

input='E:\Projects\ML'
command = "dir "+input+' /s /b '
os.system(command)
status=subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '),shell=False,text=True,cwd=input,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while status.wait()!=0:
    time.sleep(1)
print(status.communicate())
```

with `os.system()` the command is giving appropriate results but with `Popen()` I'm facing below problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\ArchiveViewer\PythonR&D\EncriptionWithPopen\runLocalCMD.py", line 9, in <module>
    status=subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '),shell=False,text=True,cwd=input,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\nmaiya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\nmaiya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I know that if I set `shell=True` the command will run, but is there any reason why it is not working with `shell=Fales`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir` is an internal command inside cmd.exe, there is no dir.exe that can be started as a process.

`system("xyz")` is internally executed as something like `cmd.exe /C xyz` on Windows.

Comment: thank you for the response, with your login I need to append  `cmd.exe /C` at the beginning of the command then.

Comment: Just use shell=True

Comment: It worked, I changed  `command = "cmd /c dir "+input+' /s /b '`

Comment: usage of `shell=True` was flagged as a risk in security scanning.